# How do I do an operation by pressing the button

Tags: html, css, web

I have set the length of the box to 0 and I want when I press the button the length becomes another value
Unfortunately the code does not work and the code is like this:

```css
    .down button: focus .info {
         height: 200px;
    }
```

The pictures and the attached code explain more.
I just want, when pressing the button, to turn the length of the other box into another value.
It looks like a click feature to show more
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cmke.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irOfW.png)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

section {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: 560px;
}

.box {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.down {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}

.down button {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #bbb;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

.down button:focus .info {
  height: 200px;
}

.down img {
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>COMSEC</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>title <br>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <p>
          TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
          TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
          TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
          TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> TEXT
          TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <button><img src="down.png" alt="BUTTON"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem explained**

In your example what you want isn't possible since you cannot traverse back up (parent) in CSS (to bad). Your button is **outside** the 'info' container and you cannot go 'back' up the parent when the button is clicked and target a child of the parent.

In your code:

```
.down button:focus .info {
     height: 200px;
}
```

'.info' is seen by the browser as a **child** element. According to this, your '.info' element should be residing inside the button element.

If you want to keep your HTML structure you need to use JavaScript for opening/closing the description. Which also gives you more flexibility.

**Answer pure CSS**

If you want it purely CSS only you could do something like below, but it is only possible when the description is right next to it. This only works on a focus, so if an user clicks somewhere else the description collapses again.

I would advice a JavaScript solution, since then it can keep being open/visible and close again on another click on the button.

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.accordion-description {
  display: none;
}

.accordion_btn {
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.accordion_btn:focus {
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 255, 1);
}

.accordion_btn:active + .accordion-description,
.accordion_btn:focus + .accordion-description {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <button type="button" class="accordion_btn">Show</button>
  <div class="accordion-description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat mauris nec eros sollicitudin sodales vel quis lectus. Vestibulum finibus, dui et convallis rutrum, velit nisl faucibus dolor, nec ultricies velit arcu id justo. Nulla suscipit vehicula magna, et tempor dolor mollis eget. Morbi vehicula, sem at ornare elementum, urna mauris elementum risus, id tristique sem massa ut metus. Curabitur convallis augue egestas, luctus velit condimentum, tristique sapien. Phasellus non nisl quis ex ultrices dignissim. Sed ut eros tincidunt, congue est id, elementum purus. Etiam lobortis felis non lacus laoreet, in lobortis nisi tempus. Donec sem nunc, efficitur vel auctor quis, ornare vel ipsum. 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Extra**

If you want to know which options you have for your CSS selectors, you can check the W3 site or MDN (Mozilla) site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors

Comment: Yes I know
Now he works with you, but I am, where is the mistake? Why does he not work?

Comment: Hi, the mistake was already in the answer, but I understand it was maybe a little to short. I've added a more detailed explanation.